# How to use spinnaker Update a pipeline definition API

Tags: spinnaker

I am trying to use this update pipeline definition API
https://spinnaker-api.svc.k8s.pinadmin.com/swagger-ui.html#!/pipeline45controller/updatePipelineUsingPUT
Any example for what should I pass in pipeline parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try examples from "Save Pipeline" stage - [link](https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/commit/9ae64a9040986ec2685c61cede090807f8706f11#diff-7fa8b7a152554a177280d92fd6a2f1b9).

Something like that:

```
{
  "name": "just waiting",
  "description": "",
  "parameterConfig": [],
  "notifications": [],
  "triggers": [],
  "stages": [
    {
      "refId": "wait1",
      "requisiteStageRefIds": [],
      "type": "wait",
      "waitTime": "420"
    }
  ],
  "expectedArtifacts": [],
  "keepWaitingPipelines": false,
  "limitConcurrent": true
}
```